# How to export the compared difference of two files as text or HTML in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: file, visual-studio-code, export, diff

Visual Studio Code has built-in function to compare the difference of two files on the UI.
[image]

I am using VS Code on Windows. Is there a convenient way to export the difference into a text or HTML file, like using the unix shell command `diff` or `vimdiff` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not specifically using VS Code:
**Export to HTML**, if the Windows can run the `vimdiff` shell command:

```
vimdiff -c TOhtml -c "w vimdiff_export.html | qa!" file1 file2
```

**Export to text** using `diff`:

```
diff file1 file2 > diff_export.txt
```

Or use the Windows command line `fc` (file compare) command:

```
fc file1 file2 > fc_export.txt
```

Comment: I used `diff -U 1000 file1 file2 > diff_export.txt` (-U = unified style, 1000 = lines of 'context' to show) that made it look closer to the vscode output when viewing unified diff